# How to remove the Xframe Options header in django?

Tags: python, django, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have made a page which has an `iframe`. Inside the `iframe` I want to show multiple different links like an article from facebook, or news, or youtube video or any other possible URL. But, due to the Xframe header, I am unable to do so. I referred to the following link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/clickjacking/
and
[Django XFrameOptionsMiddleware (X-Frame-Options) - allow iframe by client IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773005/django-xframeoptionsmiddleware-x-frame-options-allow-iframe-by-client-ip)

but didn't get any help.

My settings.py file's `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` is:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

From http://django-secure.readthedocs.org/en/latest/middleware.html , I found that using the decorator `@frame_deny_exempt` my problem can be solved. Still, I am getting the same error in chrome console i.e. 
`Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.`

Any help with this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got something wrong here if I understand well. `X-Frame-Options` is about the browser honouring your header on whether *your* site will be allowed within an iframe rather than allowing a third site within your iframe.

Respectively, this happens from the other site's headers. So for example facebook has set the above header to `DENY` and therefore any browser honouring this will not allow your site to present it no matter what your site's headers are.

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot for clarifying my problem... :)

Answer (score 9):

Remove `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` from `MIDDLEWARE` list in settings.py

Comment: Hoooolly thanks ! NGINX and Django where sending both DENY, so the header was `X-Frame-Options DENY, DENY` ...

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of Django sites and someone wanted to show them in an iframe. It was not possible because of the "x-frame-options" header values is always SAMEORIGIN. I could not remove the "x-frame-options" header value no matter what I did.

So finally I decided to do the last resort solution, which is to modify httpd.conf. I added this line:

```
  Header always set X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL
```

And it is shown in an iframe.